# Is it possible to move files from PC to USB, CD or external hard drive when recovering data?

Tags: data-recovery

My computer won't work so im going to see if I can use Ubuntu to recover my data. I am planning to use Ubuntu to move the pictures from my computer to my external hard drive. Is that possible?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/139256/data-recovery-through-ubuntu-11-10

Answer (score 1):

You can boot form the Ubuntu CD, and  get the choose Try Ubuntu, once you get the desktop, you can open file manager, and mount your drives.  If these drives are windows drives, the you might want to look at [Mounting Windows Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions).  Once that's done you can view the contents of your partitions, and at that point you can copy the data that you want.

If what you want is data recovery, then take a look at [Data Recovery With TestDisk](http://www.howtoforge.com/data_recovery_with_testdisk).

Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Should work. Boot Ubuntu, plug in the external drive, and copy over the data. Data recovery of course depends on the underlying problem.

See also -

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/