# D drive not showing

Tags: data-recovery, disk-management

My hard disk which under Windows 7 was separated into 2 partitions: C (system part) and D. I keep my movies, music and files on D and use C for installed programs. When I installed Ubuntu 16.04, I selected free space partition as Linux's system directory. After installation however, the D partition completely disappeared. I can still see my C, but D is not visible on Windows and Linux. In Windows' disk manager, it is showing some 293 GB unallocated space, while on Linux it shows as a Linux filesystem. I am very much worried about my data which was on D. I want my data back. I can't understand what's going on and will be really thankful for any replies.

Here's a screenshot if it helps somehow:

[image]

Comment: What is the output of:        sudo fdisk -l

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot mount some partitions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/775579/cannot-mount-some-partitions)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you formatted your msdos d partition into a ext4 filesystem when you installed Ubuntu, unless you remember setting up another partition specifically to install Ubuntu into when you were installing?