# How can I recover partitioned data of windows 7 after formatting with Ubuntu 16 and how can I get past grub rescue mode?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, data-recovery

I need help regarding recovery of partion files and data.

I have installed Ubuntu 16 from a pendrive but it deleted all the files and folders as well as partitions data. To recover that partition data, I installed TestDisk and analyzed. I selected the partition to be written and it said to restart the system.

After I restarted there is an error like `No such partition. Entering Grub mode` and I couldn't open anything.

How can I fix this?

please need help Urgently..

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Did you list the files with Testdisk? Did they show up? In any case you will not be able to simply "restore" the partition as it was before. Extract the files you need, back them up and then reinstall Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering NTFS partitions that cannot be mounted](http://askubuntu.com/questions/775579/recovering-ntfs-partitions-that-cannot-be-mounted)