# Recover data from lost windows partition when install ubuntu

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery

I was using a Windows 8 laptop. One day I tried to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 but accidentally I choose the option "erase disk and install Ubuntu", so I lost my Windows partition and data.

I clicked on "Install now" but when I got prompt that it will delete entire HDD then I click back but I already erase disk first.

Now I haven't write anything on the HDD. Do I have to install win 8 as first 20GB and then recover it or recover using live CD? I have experience of recovering data but it changes the file name and directory structure. I would like to know a good software app that can recover all data as it was before.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/q/775579/271