# How to recover data in Ubuntu saved as windows partition?

Tags: data-recovery

I am a novice at Ubuntu. I had windows 10 installed in my laptop with 500gb of space which had 4 partitions. I tried Ubuntu 16.4 from Live CD but when I tried restarting the system I could not boot windows as it says “windLoad.exe is missing”. Plus reinstalling the windows shows only partition now which it says cannot be used to installing windows. How can I recover my data from the HD. Please suggest as data is critical.

**My current partition layout:**
[image: my current partition layout]
**output of vgdisplay:**
[image: vgdisplay]

Comment: Did you install over the whole hard disk or just dualboot?

Comment: No i didnt install, I was trying it with live USB. Please let me know for any info to dig deeper into the issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: if you didn't uninstall Windows, something removed your windload.exe file. Are you sure this was Ubuntu's fault?

Comment: Yes, specifically while using live USB, i tried installing ubuntu but on checking the disk status, i cancelled the installation. And when I restarted my machine. I faced this issue.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by checking the disk status?

Comment: Means the part where I need to select a partition for installation. On that step, I canceled the installation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52181/discussion-between-nitin-saxena-and-mark-yisri).

Comment: added the snapshot of sudo vgdisplay.

Comment: @DavidFoerster based on chat, not a dupe

Comment: Thanks guys for helping with this. Just for the information, even after deleting the partitions, i tried using testDisk and yes i am able to get back atleast some of my useful stuff back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/775579/recovering-broken-or-deleted-ntfs-partitions)