# Can I recover Windows files from a dual-boot (Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10) overwritten by Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

I wanted to format Ubuntu partition by Ubuntu LiveUSB, but I accidentally format both Ubuntu and Windows partition. Now there is only a partition containing Ubuntu.
I'm trying to use TestDisk from LiveUSB, but with Quick Search it finds only Ubuntu old files and with Deeper Search it finds several MS Data partitions that can't be opened because "filesystems are damaged".
If possible, I would like to see the whole process to recover Windows files step-by-step, because I don't want to deep search again uselessly (it took me 32 hours).

Comment: possibly similar: http://askubuntu.com/q/874475/595510

Comment: Not exactly the same situation: I overwrote both partitions with a single partition (I had Ubuntu one of 1 TB and Windows one of 2 TB, now there is one of 3 TB), so when TestDisk scans the partition, it finds only the "Ubuntu part" of the 3 TB partition, but not the "Windows part".

Answer (score 0):

Actually I discovered by myself that restoring previous partitions with TestDisk is impossible in my situation. Nevertheless, I still had the possibility to save all my data thanks to PhotoRec, which puts any possible disk file in a chosen directory (in my case, a 2 TB external hard disk), even if not sorted by folders, because this program checks linearly in the disk any possible file with a proper extension (.png, .jpg, .txt...).
This link below is a great tutorial about how to use PhotoRec:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step#Select_where_recovered_files_should_be_written

Comment: so PhotoRec scans your disk and looks for files?

Comment: Yes, not any file, but supported ones (I don't know if mp4 and iso files can be saved, I hope that these files are classified as "others").