# /dev/sda: Input/output error

Tags: boot, hard-drive, data-recovery, io

This morning my dual boot (ubuntu 16.04/Win10) Lenovo x230i laptop showed the GRUB2 menu on power up, then decided to hang dead. After reboot it behaves as if there is no bootable disk, even though it sees HDD in BIOS and is able to run bad sector check on it.

Loading from Ubuntu Live CD I can not access the `/dev/sda` disk by any means, all I see is 467 Gb of unallocated disk space and i/o error.

1. Any routine to try and recover the HDD?
2. If my HDD is (like it probably is) dead, any way to recover data?

Update:

Lenovo bad sector check fixed like 400 sectors, and now the disk can be accessed with no error. It still appears as unallocated space with no partitions. Gpart program is now doing is check and seems to have found two partitions 349 mb each (the system ones). I assume the hdd must be fried and I can get some data out at most.

Comment: It is a bit of a long shot, but I would try the cable. Perhaps it doesn't fit well. Otherwise, put the drive in another laptop and see if it comes alive.

Comment: Your first point will have wildly different answers if you are talking about the NTFS part or the Linux part (I assume EXT4). The first would actually be a duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/q/775579/271