# Dual boot, Windows 10 won't load - immediately redirects back to GRUB

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, ntfs

I am like a newborn in the world of Ubuntu and really hoping  someone can help me.

I attempted **Ubuntu 16.04** + **Windows 10 dual boot** on my DELL XPS 13. Windows was installed first, then Ubuntu. Right now I am left with Ubuntu only, as selecting Windows Boot Manager / Windows Boot UEFI loader from GRUB does nothing but show the DELL loading logo for a few seconds, then turn back to the GRUB menu.

Windows Fast Startup was turned off before installing Ubuntu, secure boot is also disabled. I can boot Ubuntu, but not Windows.

I have tried Boot-repair, it did not solve the problem.

Boot-info goes as follows:
http://paste2.org/GOK7t8MD

Thank you for any ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Somehow your Windows partition is corrupted. The Boot-Repar is quite clear about it: **Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault**, or (...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775579/recovering-broken-or-deleted-ntfs-partitions)

Comment: Did you shrink the NTFS partition from within Windows and then reboot so it can run  chkdsk? Chkdsk always required after resize. And you can only run chkdsk from Windows repair console, either f8 with direct Windows boot (grub does not normally give time for f8 also) or Windows installer that has repair console.