# Recover data from external hdd that was moved

Tags: data-recovery, mv

I have moved some files from my external HDD (NTFS system), then had some problems with PC where I had to format it.

Is there any way to recover data that I moved from the HDD two days ago?

Comment: Have you tried running file recovery programs on the HDD and internal drive? It's possible that the files are still present. This might be a starting place.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775579/recovering-broken-or-deleted-ntfs-partitions)

Comment: If you formatted, it's the same as a deleted NTFS partition.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/463094/225694)