# Unrecognizing arguments ( recuperabit )

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, data-recovery, windows-10, ntfs

I am trying to recover my data from a ntfs partition.

I am using **recuperabit** .

I only want to recover the files of a particular folder.

folder name is **reactNative**.

partition is labelled as **bakup**.

command I tried:

```
rb main.py /media/ubuntu/bakup/reactNative/ -o recovery -s recovered
```

**error:**

```
rb: error: unrecognized arguments: /media/ubuntu/bakup/reactNative/
```

Note : I have symlinked it and named it as `rb` . [This is the reference for symlink](https://eforensicsmag.com/extracting-data-damaged-ntfs-drives-andrea-lazzarotto/).

Comment: You're running a Python program with the Ruby interpreter. Try `python main.py ...`

Comment: @NonnyMoose no no I have symlinked it and named as rb

Comment: Oh, okay. I just want to note that this could break many Ruby programs...

Comment: @NonnyMoose Ok ! actually I am on live usb so it will be deleted automatically when I ll shutdown. Its temporary

Comment: I *suspect* (based on the usage section of the [RecuperaBit github page](https://github.com/Lazza/RecuperaBit) ) that you need to specify the options **before** the path i.e. `rb main.py  -o recovery -s recovered /media/ubuntu/bakup/reactNative/`

Comment: @steeldriver already tried that too

Comment: Would you mind telling us why you are trying to pass a folder to RecuperaBit instead of a raw disk image or a block device?

Answer (score 0):

#### The command line you typed does not make sense

> **Note:** I am the author of both the essay you linked and RecuperaBit itself.

The article is pretty clear about symlinking the main RecuperaBit executable:

```
ln -s /opt/RecuperaBit/main.py /usr/local/bin/recuperabit
```

Given that you are linking to the `main.py` program, you must not reference it again while running the software. Your command then would become:

```
recuperabit /media/ubuntu/bakup/reactNative/ -o recovery -s recovered
```

But again there is no way this would work. You are referencing a directory while the only mandatory argument of RecuperaBit is **the disk image that you want to analyze.** Or, at worst, a block device (this is not advised but may work).

A meaningful command could be similar to:

```
recuperabit /path/to/the/disk/image.dd -o recovery/ -s scan.save
```

All of these points are thoroughly discussed in the aforementioned article and [here on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271).

Comment: what if I dont have the image?...will it be created by ddrescue?

Comment: Read the instructions please.