# How to recover lost data after installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery, testdisk, photorec

This has been asked quite a few times before but I want to add something extra hence a new question. Please take a moment before marking it as a duplicate.

I had dual booting with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.04 but later thought would replace it with only Ubuntu 16.04. I also had a partition on Windows to store personal data. While creating partitions for fresh Ubuntu installation I accidentally formatted the backup partition instead of the Windows partition.

I am now more keen to find out the list of files that I have lost in the process. I will be more or less okay if I can't recover the data.

From similar answers on data recovery it seems [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)/[photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) is the tool of choice. But I want to know how I can effectively run this from a Ubuntu Live USB stick. When I tried to use Photorec I got an error saying - not enough free space available (I chose an external drive with 700GB free space). If I try using Testdisk it takes a lot of time analyzing the drive (1TB HDD deeper search). As of now my main requirement is to store the list of deleted files in a log or text file.

While I read the testdisk documentation if any expert can help me will be appreciated!

**NOTE**: Before format the partition was in NTFS and after EXT4

Comment: Listing the contents of a damaged, deleted or partially overwritten NTFS drive? Here's Recuperabit. :) (disclaimer: I am the developer) https://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271