# error 0×c000000f for entering to windows 8, after installling ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, boot, windows-8

I had windows 8 on my laptop, and wanted to install ubuntu 16.04 beside windows. so i chose "Something else" option while installation and I chose a disk for ubuntu and my mistake was that chose that disk for bootloader too :( so ubuntu didn't install completely and I can't enter my windows too. A BSOD showed and the error was "INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE". and I install again ubuntu, this time completely (didn't do that mistake again) and now I have ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. but when I start my laptop, there are some option, ubuntu 16.04 and some memory things and the last one is windows 8 and when i want to enter it a message come and said that i have no recovery and said to plug in usb or dvd of windows and error 0×c000000f showed under that and if I continue it will that BSOD again and restart.
and the point is that I don't have other Volume of my laptop in ubuntu except one Volume which I install Windows (C) on that.

Do I lost my drives or I can have them again?
What should I do now?

updated:
and now i enter two terminal codes

```
    mmd@mmd-Inspiron-3521:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda4   8:4    0 560.4G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  97.7G  0 part /media/mmd/8A90E0AE90E0A245
├─sda3   8:3    0 273.4G  0 part /
└─sda1   8:1    0 992.5K  0 part 
mmd@mmd-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for mmd: 
Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB  primary
 2      1049kB  105GB   105GB   primary  ntfs         boot
 3      105GB   398GB   294GB   primary  ext4
 4      398GB   1000GB  602GB   primary
```

and I have sda2 of first list(number 2 of second list)

and my 602GB disk was actually two disks around 300GB disks in windows before installing ubuntu.

Comment: It's not clear whether you have damaged Windows or just overwritten the Windows bootloader, but if it's just a Windows bootloader issue then read the answers to this question: [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix).

Comment: and do you have any idea for disk problem?

Comment: [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775579/recovering-broken-or-deleted-ntfs-partitions)