# Accidental part-format of an external 2TB Seagate HDD - How to recover data?

Tags: 16.04, mount, hard-drive, gparted

I accidentally started to write to my Seagate 2TB HDD. I now find it doesn't mount though it does show up on gparted, Partition - Unallocated,  File System - Unallocated, Size - 1.82TB

BTW I have downloaded and made  bootable disks of Knoppix 7, Systemrescue 6.0.3,and GParted Live but am not having much, in fact any, success so far.
How can I mount the drive and hopefully recover the data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775579/recovering-broken-or-deleted-ntfs-partitions) and [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/)

Comment: It reads like you've overwritten (via format) the partition table, meaning there's nothing to `mount`.  The data on the drives (some or most of it) may exist, but you'll need to re-create your partition table which is a long process covered in the duplicate links (and not just a `mount` & `cp` of files; backups exist for that purpose).

Comment: I have a very similar situation and want to use chkdsk as suggested in a previous post but get 'E: Unable to locate package chkdsk'