# Drive partition recovery. I want to recover files before using it for Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, drive

'''Unable to access the drive after Ubuntu installation. This partition belongs to windows but I wanted to allocate some parts for Ubuntu during installation. But I see this drive. I have important data in his drive and now want to recover it for windows. I installed Ubuntu on my SSD and allocated 25GB and I wanted some extra space for Ubuntu from my HDD. That's Why I choose that drive so that Ubuntu can use that drive to use. But Ubuntu totally converted that HDD drive partition which is 180GB in size. I can Use Ubuntu because It was installed on My SSD drive. I have included both my SSD and HDD screenshot here. In [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOm7K.png) link is my HDD where I want to recover my desired drive. And in the [enter image description here] link I have added my SSD screenshot where I installed my drive.
'''[This is my HDD where the selected drive which I want to recover.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOm7K.png) I want to use this drive for Ubuntu after copying all files from it to my external device.

[This is my SSD where I installed Ubuntu and running normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa64W.png)

Comment: Windows has no native support for EXT4. There are a few apps than can enable it but are NOT recommended in a dual-boot because the risk of data corruption while using those is very real. Anyway this isn't an Ubuntu question.

Comment: My drive transformed into this during Ubuntu installation. Now I cant access to this drive from Ubuntu and Windows also. Please help me to recover the drive.

Comment: There might be some terminology confusion -- in the Linux world, a partition is never a drive or a disk.  So it looks like you assigned your /home to an existing partition with files on it (ntfs filesystem?), then specified an ext4 filesystem on it. Maybe you could just change it back to (ntfs?) if you didn't format it, but the fact that there are 30+GB in use on the ext4 partition is confusing.  I take this as a recovery question, after that, you can do what you want with the partition. What was the original type of filesystem?  Did you format it for ext4?  What are the 30+GB there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775579/recovering-broken-or-deleted-ntfs-partitions)

Comment: You got my exact problem. Maybe you are an ubuntu expert. I have an SSD I installed my Ubuntu OS there. Then I assigned /Home to an existing NTFS drive. I used the ubuntu recovery app for backup. It takes that 30GB files.

Answer (score 0):

That partition has ext4 file system. Ext4 is the most common Linux file system and is not supported on Windows by default. You can't use view and use that partition in Windows. If you have still have important data in that which are undeleted, just copy those files to another ntfs partition. OR if it has been formatted, then you can use testdisk.

Comment: Actually, I am totally new to Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 21.04, Now I cant install any app from Ubuntu app store. I did not formated this drive but during installation, I chose /home for that drive. Now I cant access to this drive from Ubuntu also. Can you Please tell me how to copy those files?

Comment: Do you *really* have personal files you need to backup from that partition? It seems that you just installed and not really used Ubuntu. That being the case you can format or remove said partitions. Otherwise, if the installed Ubuntu doesn't boot or work correctly you can easily access what you need from live session, the same way you installed Ubuntu. If neither of the aforementioned hypotheses than this whole question is nonsense.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on my SSD and allocated 25GB and I wanted some extra space for Ubuntu from my HDD. Thats Why I choose that drive so that Ubuntu can use that drive to use. But Ubuntu totally converted that HDD drive partition which is 180GB in size. You can see the picture. I can Use Ubuntu because It was installed in My SSD drive.

Comment: You need to improve your question and give us enough details to help you.  If you want help you will need to be clearer in your question about what it is you are trying to do. You need to include actionable details and enough context that we know what is going on. Before asking, make sure that you search and research about your problem. When asking, show us what you found and tell us why it doesn't work for you, or be explicit in what you need help understanding.  If you have more than one question, ask them separately. We are here to help but it is a two way street.

Comment: thanks, got assured... I will try to improve the question

Comment: I edited my post, should I post it again?