Installed - lost data
I installed Ubuntu 20.04 through flash drive, installed on my second drive (I have 2 of them).
And in installing I wanted to choose empty space I made for it, but it wasn't able to use it and I chose installing Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows.
I left 120 GB to Linux (1 TB drive) and it installed, but now I can't mount or access files. I had EVERYTHING on my drive and I can't lose it. I tried both Ubuntu and Windows, but neither was able to load files. I didn't do anything to the drive yet. What should I do?
(I was really dumb.)
And no, I don't have any other PC or anything, I only have one PC.
When I try to check, mount, and do filesystem stuff it gives me an error, wrong format if I'm not wrong.
That's my GParted data, it's marked with red.

I opened information about disk, it says:
Unable to read the contents of this file system! 
Because of this some operations may be unavailable. 
The cause might be a missing software package. 
The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support: 
  e2fsprogs v1.41+.


Done...? What else you need? It kinda takes long to boot up in ubuntu, i can record some stuff trough ubuntu or windows if you need.

Boot the live USB installer and click the Try Ubuntu button to run an Ubuntu live session. Open GParted app, view the 2 drives, and take a screenshot of the partitioning. Upload the screenshot(s) to any image or file storage website and edit your question with a link to the screenshot(s) so that we can understand your problem better.

Cam i do it trough windows? P.S alr im booting

Use the USB flash drive that you installed Ubuntu 20.04 through.

I did, im currenly using flash/TryUbuntu mode right now (Also talking trough it)
P.S. It says:
Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support:  e2fsprogs v1.41+.

Does this answer your question? How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?

I cant find 'Ubuntu system settings > Software & updates'

Search for Software & Updates in the applications dashboard (Dash) and click its icon to launch it..

Oh Thanks, ill continue

I dont have any other drive to save it.. only C: drive where i have windows and other eiportant files (300 GB)

This answer should help: https://askubuntu.com/a/776317/ but you will need to get a cheap external SSD to store the data anyway.

..., it means that i have to lose everything... i really cant buy anything, what if i format drive to ntfs? it will delete my data right?

In any case you don't have to lose everything because it's usually possible to quick recover all the data after an accidental quick partition reformatting because all the data is still there on the disk and intact even after it has been reformatted.

What should i do then? I really need to do smth right now, i either recover data or format disk to make windows access it

Use this query on Google Gemini or ChatGPT: "A disk with a Windows 10 ntfs partition on it was accidentally quick reformatted as ext4. The Windows OS on the disk is still intact, not overwritten. How to recover the lost ntfs partition using testdisk?"

It gave me something, currently doing that, thanks
